# How to use lead or Lag for a Group in oracle or any other analytic function to get desired result?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

input

```
id   name     date   value
1     aa      x      v1
1     aa      y      v1
1     aa      z      v1
2     bb      a      v2
2     bb      b      v2
3     cc      c      v2
4     dd      d      v3
4     dd      e      v3
5     ee      f      v4
```

output

```
   id   name     date   value  lead value
    1     aa      x      v1      v2
    1     aa      y      v1      v2
    1     aa      z      v1      v2
    2     bb      a      v2      v2
    2     bb      b      v2      v2
    3     cc      c      v2      v3
    4     dd      d      v3      v4
    4     dd      e      v3      v4
    5     ee      f      v4     null
```

How to get lead value for a id? i.e for id 1 lead value is v2,for id 2 lead value again is v2(as id 3 value is v2), for id 3 lead value is v3 and so on..

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your expected lead values.  Can you explain it?

Comment: I want to apply lead function but for a group. Let me explain, for id =1 and name =aa I want next  row value(for id =2 and name = bb i.e v2). For id = 2 and name = bb next row value( for id= 3 and name = cc i.e again v2). For id= 3 and name = cc next row value (for id=4 and name =dd i.e v3). Basically calculating lead() but for a group(id,name).

Comment: Why does `v2` appear across both `v1` and `v2` groups?

Comment: in the input , for id 2 and 3 value is v2 So, For id 1 we want the value for id 2 i.e v2, For id id 2 we want the value for id 3 ie again v2. As v2 appears in the input twice So it is in the output for two groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query to get the desired result:

```
with 
CTE1(ID, VALUE) AS
(select distinct id, 
 value from table1 
 order by id
),
CTE2 AS
(
SELECT A.ID, 
  A.VALUE, 
  LEAD(A.VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY A.ID) LEAD_VALUE 
FROM CTE1 A
)
SELECT A.*, B.LEAD_VALUE 
FROM TABLE1 A, CTE2 B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID;
```

[DB_FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9335/22)